# What books cover Fey Pact Warlocks and their awesome masters?

Tags: dnd-4e, feywild, warlock

What books (and magazine articles) provide background (3rd party material okay)? Please specify as much detail as possible for indicating if the resource has enough detail to make worthwhile.

*I saw [this question for Star Pact Warlocks](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1766/what-books-cover-star-pact-warlocks-and-their-awful-masters), but I play a fey pact warlock, and want a similarly awesome answer!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK! You want the *Manual of the Planes* to start with. It's got an entire section on the Feywild, which parenthetically was written by John Rogers, mastermind behind the TV show *Leverage*, which has an RPG based on it. (But don't buy the *Leverage* RPG, it won't help you with fey pact warlocks.)

The aforementioned ["Performing the Pact"](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/drcact/20091116) continues to be useful for the same reasons it was useful for star pact warlocks -- good roleplay advice, and some nice mechanical benefits.

Unfortunately, there's no fey pact equivalent of the really good star pact warlock article. There is, however, a great Feywild article: ["Court of Stars: Prince of Frost."](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/drfe/20090424) It's mostly background material about the Prince of Frost, a powerful evil fey being. There are also several pages in the back directly addressing warlock pacts with the Prince, including both roleplaying material and mechanical crunch.

Similarly, *Dungeon* had a Creature Incarnations article on [Fomorians](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/drcinc/2010March). It's not oriented towards warlocks, but if you're looking for great stuff on the Feywild, it's worth reading.

If you're looking for adventures, *King of the Trollhaunt Warrens* takes place in and around the Feywild. I don't find it hugely evocative of the fey spirit except maybe in the last section, but it does offer one perspective. Similarly, the RPGA module *The Lady in Flames* is strongly Feywild flavored.

Continuing to third party resources, Goodman Games comes to our aid again, with [*Creature Cache 4: Fey Folk*](http://goodmangames.rpgnow.com/product_info.php?products_id=60693). It's purely a monster book, so if you want more Feywild denizens, it's where to go. Kobold Quarterly has a fey-themed adventure, [*Courts of the Shadow Fey*](http://www.koboldquarterly.com/KQStore/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=5&products_id=88&zenid=ee368ec39494a1fe790ff3f50c5b03c1), which might also be useful.

Answer (score 1):

This post [Archfey of the Feywild](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/19781386/Archfey_of_the_Realms), on the WotC forums, seems to provide a comprehensive list, along with references to the sourcebooks:

> Manual of the Planes
>   Arcane Power
>   Dragon Magazine issues 352,374,376
>   Dungeon Magazine issues 159,165

It also mentions the novel Plague of Spells, by Bruce R. Cordell.